# Linux environment variables of all processes

Tags: linux, environment-variables

To get environment variables of specific process we use the next command:

```
cat /proc/<pid>/environ | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Is there similar command to list all environment variables from all processes?
And is there one more similar command to list all values of specific environment variable from all processes?

Comment: Please note that the */proc/<pid>/environ* file only shows the env vars when the process was instantiated. It does not show the **current** env vars. That API is a great example of an anti-API; i.e., an API that should never have been created. Or at least should have been named something like `initial-environ`. See, for example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-environment-variables-of-a-process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a list of all process IDs, you can use this one-liner:

```bash
ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n +2
```

What this does, in three steps:

- `ps -ef` List process info of all processes running on the system, in standard format. Prints with a header row.
- `awk '{print $2}'` Print just the second section, splitting by whitespace. The format of `ps -ef` shows lines as `UID`, `PID`, `PPID`, `C`, `STIME`, `TTY`, `TIME`, and finally `CMD`. We only want the second one, so the `awk` command only gets the second column.
- `tail -n +2` Cuts out the first line and only outputs the second line onwards. As mentioned previously, the `ps -ef` command has a header row, so we need to cut that for a bare list of PIDs.

To list all the environment variables for all of these PIDs, we can use the `environ` files as you mentioned. To do this, we'll use a `for` loop with an evaluated command (between the backticks).

```bash
for pid in `ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n +2`;
    do cat /proc/${pid}/environ;
done;
```

or this handy one-liner:

```bash
for pid in `ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n +2`; do cat /proc/${pid}/environ; done;
```

This `for` loop goes through that list of PIDs, assigning the variable `pid` to each iteration, and executes the `cat` command on each file with the PID in the path.

For readability, we can use `strings` or `tr`, both shown below.

```bash
for pid in `ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n +2`; do strings /proc/${pid}/environ | cat; done;

for pid in `ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n +2`; do tr '\0' '\n' </proc/${pid}/environ | cat; done;
```

You could also use tools such as `cut`, `sed`, `xargs`, or anything else that gets the job done.

For finding specific environment variables, you can pipe all of that into `grep` instead of `cat`, which will automatically print to the console:

```bash
for pid in `ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n +2`; do strings /proc/${pid}/environ | grep "SHELL"; done;
```

Comment: Looks nice with xargs: `ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n +2 | xargs -I{} cat /proc/{}/environ | tr '\0' '\n'`

Comment: No need for the `tail` .. `ps -ef | awk 'NR>1{print $2}'`

Comment: Your answer does not list the **current** env vars of all processes. It shows the **initial** env vars; i.e., those when the process was instantiated. If the process subsequently modified its env vars those modifications will not be reflected in the output of your "solution". Which is why I down-voted your answer.

Comment: @KurtisRader thank you for mentioning this. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70636 this answer, on another question, details how you can read current processes' environment variables, though it is slightly arduous. however, I would guess that most everyday programs won't be changing their own environment variables, since it is often pointless or better done elsewhere.